# PHP Mongo Query NOT NULL

Tags: php, mongodb

Anyone know the syntax for writing a php-mongo query to use `NOT NULL`?

I know how to do this when I query for `NULL`:

```
<?php
$cursor = $collection->find(array("someField" => null));
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yeah, you want the `$ne` operator, so

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("someField" => array('$ne' => null)));
```

Comment: Thanks Jim. I just tried to post the same answer... but I don't have enough rep yet. I will accept your answer as soon as it will let me.

Comment: @jim Should be single quotes because of the `$`.

Comment: whoops on single quotes...haven't written php in a long time

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the [same kind of queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying) you would use on the Mongo console, you pass as an array to the query methods.

In your case, it could be (if you're checking that the field exists - note that the field could just be absent from the document):

`array("someField" => array('$exists' => true))`

Or to check if it's not equal to null:

`array("someField" => array('$ne' => null))`

Watch out for the `$` in double quotes, since PHP will consider that a variable.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I was wondering how to check whether or not the field exists.

Comment: @MichaelIrey Yeah, with schema-less databases, there is a difference between 'is it `null`' and 'does it exist'.